# Deploy Rails app as desktop application in windows

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, web-deployment

I have been working for the last months on a Ruby on Rails project. The problem is that where the project is going to run there is no internet and I need to run the project as if it were on localhost when the computer start or create an executable project that will be installed on the computer. The program will run in Windows and only in one computer.

I have all the project in Ruby & HTML and the database is in PostgreSQL.

Obviously if there was internet in the office it could upload it to a server and there would be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a docker container with your app environment configured and run it at system boot.

More info:
https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/intro-to-docker-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup same development environment you need using offline packages from http://railsinstaller.org/en
2. Install Ruby on Rails and configure your application / DB.
3. using Adobe air you can run web app in desktop mode. https://www.adobe.com/in/products/air.html